# Facebook like button not launching new window in Cocoa WebView

Tags: objective-c, facebook, macos, cocoa, webview

I'm using a Cocoa WebView which loads an HTML page containing social media buttons. When I click the Facebook like button, no popup window is opened at all, however others such as Twitter and Google+ work fine and launch the popup window as expected.

That same HTML page works without issue in Safari.

I believe I've implemented my WebUIDelegate properly and can't think of what else might be causing this issue. Any ideas?

```
#pragma mark WebViewUIDelegate Methods

- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *) __unused sender createWebViewWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 400, 300) styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSResizableWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
    [window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
    WebView *webView = [[WebView alloc] init];
    [webView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];
    window.contentView = webView;
    [webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
    [_popupWindows addObject:window];
    return webView;
}

- (WebView *)webView:(WebView *)sender createWebViewModalDialogWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    return [self webView:sender createWebViewWithRequest:request];
}

- (void)webViewRunModal:(WebView *)sender
{
    [sender.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

- (void)webViewShow:(WebView *)sender
{
    [sender.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

- (void)webViewClose:(WebView *)sender
{
    [_popupWindows removeObject:sender.window];
    [sender.window close];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I need to call `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` in `webView:createWebViewWithRequest:` ... the example here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/MultipleWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002026-117294 implies that this is necessary (as `openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:` will call `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`) while the documentation for `webViewShow:` seems to imply that showing the window should be its responsibility exclusively. Confusing. If anyone has a better explanation, it's welcome.